# Infer an argument's type to avoid a generic?

Tags: javascript, typescript, mapped-types, inferred-type

How can I infer `O` from the specific `obj` passed as the parameter?

```
export function pubsubs<O extends {[key: string]: Pubsub}>(
  obj: O // extends infer U ? U : never
   //        ↑
   //    (failed attempt to infer)
): {
  pub: Pubify<O>
  sub: Subify<O>
} {

  // ... generate pub and sub based on obj ...

  return {pub, sub}
}
```

Desired result:

```
const {pub, sub} = pubsubs({ // ← (want to infer from this first arg)
 //                      ↑
 //             (no generic)

  userLogout: pubsub(),
  userLoading: pubsub(),
  userError: pubsub<(error: Error) => void>(),
  userLogin: pubsub<(auth: LoginDetail) => void>(),
})

// but the typings fail to be inferred!
sub.userError(error => {})
 //            ↑
 //    (error type is 'any' )
```

Workaround without inference:

```
const input = {
  userLogout: pubsub(),
  userLoading: pubsub(),
  userError: pubsub<(error: Error) => void>(),
  userLogin: pubsub<(auth: LoginDetail) => void>(),
}

const {pub, sub} = pubsubs<typeof input>(input)
 //                         ↑
 //        (should be inferred)

// typings are preserved
sub.userError(error => {})
 //            ↑
 //       (typescript knows)
```

How can I infer the type and avoid the generic type parameter?

Comment: What is the definition of `Pubsub` and of `pubsub`?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin — while i don't suspect it's strictly relevant, here's more of the related code https://hastebin.com/ekumolokah cheers 

Comment: @ChaseMoskal Unclear to me what is not working, the example you posted with the extra code you posted above shows the exact same types for everything in both the explicit and the inference case, as far as I can tell. Could you be more explicit about what you expect and what the actual result is ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir — i have edited my question in hopes it is more clear

Comment: @ChaseMoskal Maybe this is a version thing, I tried your exact code in the playground, it all works fine. If you could post a playground link (https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) to show the issue ? Everything works for me (I would post a playground link but there is just too much code to post it in a comment)